# Ecllipse : Not able to see any file/Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I installed Eclipse luna, Android SDK, ADT (all latest) & set up everything.

Even after re-starting Eclipse I don't see Welcome to Android screen. I can only see Welcome Screen. But the settings required for Android & Java were all set I believe so, so the installation might be done properly only.

I tried creating Android projects, on last dialog i.e. select Activity type, I select, click Finish ; the screen blinks and the same page is seen. I tried with variations (using different Activity type) & create 4 projects, can see the projects created, also the activity java file in src folder is created. But on Eclipse Don't see anything. But on top title, I see the project name. 
   Similarly to chk with I tried creating Java project, same thing. It seems somethign is wrong with Eclipse. Other than WElcome Screen I don't see anything. I even tried to open just a java file - file name is seen on top, but file contents not seen on screen.

Image of how I am creating project & its results :
[image: Rest all settings are same as Deo has mentioned & Shown]

After clicking Finish & Creating files, etc, again Step 5 is on focus and on back the Initial Welcome Screen is only seen. 
If at all I click Finish again, then I get error that ApplicationName already exists.

See the Folders & Files created after clikcing Finish
[image]
The files, activity is created. So the Performing Changes has also done its work, but the view is lost ???

This is where I can't get what is happening & Why? What is going wrong here. I have only Android 5.0.1 API 21. I don't have 2.2 - Is that the reason !

Created Manifest File :

-  - - -

Can someone please help me with this. I am stuck up and am in hurry to start working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `I don't see Welcome to Android screen. I can only see Welcome Screen` ... pardon? Am I missing something as well? Since I never see such screens... But Eclipse works **perfectly**.

Comment: The welcome screen that we find when by default eclipse starts. Eclipse starts, but as said can create projects, but the wizard doen't get complete on Finish btn and nothing comes up on screen. In folder, fiels along with activity in src is seen, java file of Java project is seen in dir, but nothing in eclipse. On top the project/file name is visible, but no project explorer, files, etc. Evne not a single java file can be seen in Eclipse.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you get and what you would like to? I only have a splash screen when launching. Or an About dialog when I do `Help/About Eclipse`.

Comment: Please, make sure you make a new **Android Application Project**, not a `Java Project`.

Comment: Der Golem, As said, first I tried with 4 Android Application PRojects only. When that didn't work as accepted, I tried with Java project.

Comment: I only want that once I select Activity Type & click Finish, the project should be created & on screen the Project explorer, activity file, etc should be seen up. That is not being seen.

Comment: I think this might be a bug with Eclipse ADT. I don't know if there is any fix but a workaround is to create activities manually by adding a java class and adding a new activity entry to the AndroidManifest.xml file. I will write a complete answer with how if no one finds a better solution.

Comment: What happens when you double click on a Java file?

Comment: When I open a java file form outside i.e. explorer, on top I see "Java" & file name, but yet view only Welcome screen.

Comment: No, I mean inside Eclipse. The Java code editor should open.

Comment: Yes, but it is not opening. Not a single editor, package explorer, log cat/Console window - No window is opening. Only Welcome screen is seen.

Comment: @Tvd Before you get started, just switch to Android Studio. ADT is no longer supported. It's last update was October 2014.

Comment: Jared, I got to develop in Eclipse only. Basic requirement.

Comment: Can you experts please have alook at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557313/android-eclipse-project-could-not-build-due-to-cannot-delete-v-7appcompat    I am facing other problem hence created a new question. Please help to solve soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reset perspective? (Window -> Reset perspective)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I got it solved.

I saw 2 icons on the top left below menu bar. On clicking that I could see the project explorer & other windows. And finally closed the Welcome Screen.

Thanks a lot for everybody's effort to help me solve my problem.

Thanks once again.