# Android: Eclipse : Project could not build due to cannot delete v-7appcompat

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, android-appcompat

I have created an Android application API 21 using Eclipse luna. I have only API 21 installed on my pc. Initially I faced error of "could not find resource......" for which I found that I got to add support library v7-appcompat. Tried various ways to add the jar, nothing worked. So finally I added the appcompat project to my project. That solved that error.

Then on re-start Eclipse got new 3 errors - Unable to load API 19... (something like this) in appcompat project. In appcompat project int project.properties I changes the target API from 19 to 21. That solved 2 errors.

Now the 3rd error, that I am not able to solve :
 Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/android-support-v7-appcompat/bin/classes/android'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent    android-support-v7-appcompat        Unknown Java Problem

I deleted v4-appcompat from my project/libs folder. But yet no results. The /libs & /Android Private Libraries in appcompat both contains v4-appcompat & v7-appcompat.

In my project, I found in /bin/dexedLibs their are 3 jars - android-support-v4-c7810708df94d8bfa4383f5149ab5d83.jar, android-support-v7-appcompat-892bfc35ccacd9325da1c2c80a3f3acb.jar, android-support-v7-appcompat-c13bc4563c36037596e53cd84b2614f2.jar

Can you let me know what is the problem and how should I solve it.
Any help is highly appreciated. I am in hurry to start working on the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new project: Eclipse Luna should create automatically (if not already there) a library project called ***appcompat_v7*** when creating a new project. Also automatically a reference to the library project *appcompat_v7* is added to the new project. At that point it is ready.

Comment: GPack, yes you are right, on creating new project I did get a project named "appcompat_v7". But when created the project in colsole I got 3 errors stating "styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' for all 3 /valuesXX/style files .     In /libs also their is only android-support-v4.jar. And in problems 17 warning stating "The field ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD is deprecated" for MainActivity.java & NavigationDrawerFragment class & several other deprecated in NavigationDrawerFragment  class.

Comment: Check the new project _Properties_: Project Build Target needs Android 5.0 checked. And under Library section at the bottom, library _appcompat_v7_ needs to be well referenced (with green mark check)